# Talend - How to pass an Array from a ChildJob to a ParentJob

Tags: arrays, talend

How can I pass an array from a ChildJob to a ParentJob?

The array values came from : tExtractXMLField -> tFlowToIterate.

I've done it by using a Routine (like this: https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5671107), but I'm interesting in another approach, where Routines are no needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be very very tricky, since the only way to pass variables to a subjob is through context vars, which are Strings.

You can concat the elements of the array (in a tJavaRow, for example) and then feed a String context var to pass and split() and cast inside the child job. It's a quick-and-dirty solution, but only suitable for small arrays, obviously.

I'm afraid the official KB you linked is the most advisable way to do it, even if you need a user routine

Comment: Thank you! I think that's a way to solve my problem (The array only has 2 values). Another thing: I already have the String with the array values 'concatenated', in my subJob. They are stored in a context var. Now, I pass them to my parent job by using the option 'Copy Child Job Schema'. But, I want to use them in a next component, by using the 'OnSubjobOk' transition. So, how can I access the context from my Child Job in this next component?

Comment: To dig out data from a child job you can use a tBufferOut as last component of your child job and use an outgoing main connection on parent's tRunJob. Ofc they must share the same schema. If you need these data in a context var you can use a tIterate to convert a data connection to a signal as usual. This could help: http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5470